# Prove that for an increasing series of events, Event N is equal to the union of events 1 to N.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Question:**

Given an infinite increasing sequence of events  $E_1 \subset E_2 \subset ... \subset E_n ....$ show that
$$\bigcup_{k=1}^n E_k = E_n$$
to verify “=”, you need to use the argument “A = B if A ⊂ B and B ⊂ A"

**My Attempt:**

Obviously  $E_n \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^n E_k$ as when expanded we can see that $E_n$ is a part of $\bigcup_{k=1}^n E_k$

However I am stuck on showing that  $ \bigcup_{k=1}^n E_k \subset E_n $.

My current proof involves the fact that since each event ($E_k$) includes its previous events ($E_1$ to $E_{n-1}$) the union of a event and its previous events is just the event($E_k \cup E_{k-1} = E_k$ ). However, this is effectively the statement I am trying to prove leaving me stuck.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If $x\in\bigcup_{k=1}^n E_k$ then for some $1\leqslant j\leqslant n$, $x\in E_j\subset E_n$.

Comment: Better phrased as a statement about sets. Using "Events" implies there is something else from probability theory at play at first look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is in your union, by definition $x$ belongs to some $E_k$ with $k\le n$. But any such $E_k$ is a subset of $E_n$. That is all there is to it.

Comment: Thank you that's a very elegant way of explaining it.